# Application is deployed on cloudhub but can't reach it

Tags: deployment, mule, cloudhub

I've deployed my application on cloudhub.io after testing in on my local machine. The log says the application has been successfully deployed and is running as it should, but when i try to use it, i get a page that says : 
*If you deployed your application and expected to see something here, that means you need to change the configuration of your docroot.*

I don't understand what i have to do in this case, can't find any reference to docroot on mule's website.

EDIT: This is most of my config

```
    <sns:config name="Amazon_SNS" accessKey="*********" secretKey="********"  doc:name="Amazon SNS" region="EUWEST1">
    <sns:connection-pooling-profile initialisationPolicy="INITIALISE_ONE" exhaustedAction="WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW"/>
</sns:config>
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="${http.port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<json:object-to-json-transformer name="Object_to_JSON" doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
<flow name="CreateTopic">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/createtopic" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:create-topic config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
        <sns:create-topic-request name="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.name]"/>
    </sns:create-topic>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
<flow name="Subscribe">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/Subscribe" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:subscribe config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
        <sns:subscribe-request topicArn="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.topic]" protocol="email" endpoint="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.subscriber]"/>
    </sns:subscribe>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
<flow name="ListTopics">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/listTopics" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:list-topics config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
    </sns:list-topics>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
<flow name="Publish">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/publish" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:publish config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
        <sns:publish-request topicArn="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.topic]" message="There's new content in the topic #[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.topic]" subject="New comments on an idea - Crowdsourcing Forums" messageStructure="Raw"/>
    </sns:publish>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
<flow name="checkTopic">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/checkTopic" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <sns:get-topic-attributes config-ref="Amazon_SNS" doc:name="Amazon SNS">
        <sns:get-topic-attributes-request topicArn="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.topic]"/>
    </sns:get-topic-attributes>
</flow>
```

Comment: Can you post some relevant config of the endpoints you exposing? Also are you using the recommended ports? http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Developing+a+CloudHub+Application#DevelopingaCloudHubApplication-ProvidinganExternalHTTPorHTTPSPort

Comment: Updated topic with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the port set to 8080.

CloudHub only supports incoming traffic on port 80 of your application domain URL as described here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Developing+a+CloudHub+Application#DevelopingaCloudHubApplication-ProvidinganExternalHTTPorHTTPSPort.

You can use the http.port environment variable:

```
port="${http.port}"
```

Also set the host to 0.0.0.0

```
<http:listener-config port="${http.port}" host="0.0.0.0"
        name="http" />
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my local config, before i deployed i set the port to ${http.port} so i still have the same problem..

Comment: Well based on that, you should be able to hit: 'http://YOURAPPNAME.cloudhub.io/createtopic'

Comment: i can't, i keep getting this message, no matter what i type:

Uh-oh spaghettios! There's nothing here.

If you deployed your application and expected to see something here, that means you need to change the configuration of your docroot.

However, many integration apps don't need a user interface-- they silently work in the background integrating stuff and fighting crime.

If you need further help, please feel free to contact us.

Comment: That did it, i also had to stop my other projects and then start that one in order for it to be deployed and work correctly. Thanks Ryan!

Comment: Worked for me. I just found this article, it's a walk through for this, see Step 2: Configure the HTTP Connector: https://docs.mulesoft.com/cloudhub/getting-started-with-connectors